# How to fetch pdf response from Web Api to Android?

Tags: android, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a Web Api service which returns a pdf filestream. How to fetch this response in android and display as pdf file? My Web Api code is given below

```
[Route("api/GetPdf")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetPdf(string PdfName)
    {
        DataAccess objClsData = new DataAccess();
        SqlDataReader _SqlReader;
        _SqlReader = objClsData.ExecuteQuery("select VALUE FROM [Param] where subkey='imagepath'");

        if (_SqlReader.HasRows)
        {
            if (_SqlReader.Read())
            {
                string FileName = WebUtility.UrlDecode(PdfName);
                string PdfFile = _SqlReader["VALUE"].ToString() + "\\" + FileName + ".pdf";
                //string PdfFile = _SqlReader["VALUE"].ToString() + "\\" + "bill##8000006" + ".pdf";
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(PdfFile);
                response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

                return response;
            }
        }
        HttpResponseMessage responseError = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        return responseError;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code snippet

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(apiUrl)
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
  .build()
  .create(WebApiEndPoint.class).
  downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync("File_Url")//Change to your file name
  .enqueue(new retrofit.Callback<ResponseBody>() {


@Override
 public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) 
        {
          if (response != null && response.body() != null) {
        //response.body() will contains the downloaded file details
        }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Failed to Download file ", "");
        }
    });
```

### WebApiEndPoint.class

```
@GET("GetPdf")
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync(@Query("PdfName") String PdfName);
```